# How can i implement payment through payment with two receivers?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Working on Android Application which provides platform for users to sell and buy their used products. Below is the scenario of payment screen when User(buy) want to bought an item.

[image]

How can i do this payment with [paypal adaptive payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/). I found something  [Parallel payment api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc/)  but in this api doing parallel payment form owner's account  need same thing with dynamic customer account.Every thing needed in PHP to develop web service will be used in android application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/), specifically the [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API.  That is how you would do the split payment as either parallel or chained.

From mobile apps I typically build the web services on a server, so you can still write everything in PHP and just pass data to and from PayPal back to the app through the PHP service.  Then you make simple serice requests to your own PHP script and have it just return a basic JSON response or whatever you want to work with in the mobile app.

There may be more direct ways to get it done, but that's what I've always done and it works well.  Allows you to use your web server for more detailed logging, too.